# I Couldn't split the values .... Im wondering why (var = amt1) values are not giving space

Tags: jquery

I Couldn't split the values. I'm wondering why in the (var = amt1) values are not giving space. therefore in the `alert(amt1)` getting values like `100$200$300$`. I should supposed to get `100$ 200$ 300$`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#pa_ssl").one('change',function(){
    var amt1 = jQuery("form.cart_group").find(".component.paged:eq(0)").find("span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").text();
    alert(amt1);//i need (100$ 200$ 300$) insteat of (100$200$300$)

    var single_amt = amt1.split("Rs.");
    var amount1 = single_amt[1];
    alert(amount1);

    jQuery(".component_inner .composited_product_details_wrapper").append("Rs." + amount1 + "<br/>"); 
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't see the need for a `php` tag

Comment: sorry by the  mistake

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you edit my code

Comment: @Pradeeprajendiren I added an answer for you

Comment: @Pradeeprajendiren  try solution given by Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fine!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#pa_ssl").one('change',function(){

var amt1 = jQuery("form.cart_group").find(".component.paged:eq(0)").find(".woocommerce-variation-price span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").text();
var single_amt = amt1.split("Rs.");
var amount1 = single_amt[0];

jQuery(".component_inner .composited_product_details_wrapper").append("Rs." +amount1+"<br/>");

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `text()` on a collection of elements will concatenate all the values together as they are in the DOM without spaces. If you want to build an array of them, I'd suggest using `map()` instead.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("#pa_ssl").one('change', function(){
    var amounts = $("form.cart_group .component.paged:eq(0) span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").map(function() {
      return $(this).text().replace('Rs.', '');
    }).get();

    var amount1 = amounts[1];
    console.log(amount1);

    $(".component_inner .composited_product_details_wrapper").append("Rs." + amount1 + "<br/>"); 
  });
});
```

Comment: The OP didn't have the privelege to comment. So made an edit request to your answer trying to say something to you. Consider checking it.

Comment: @SagarV I didn't get your edit - I think the OP overwrote your edit as they also attempted to edit, but it was rejected as an attempt to reply.

Comment: @Pradeeprajendiren use `join(' ');` on the array to build a space-separated string

Comment: Yes. Not me, The OP made an edit request and I am the person rejected it Saying an attempt to replay

Comment: Aaah, ok, that makes sense now

Comment: No problem. You should consider accepting an answer, or adding your own to help those who visit this question in future and have the same problem